# Setting up my server to send emails using IMAP and a custom domain

Tags: server, email

Objective:
Send an email via CLI using a my email address via IMAP, making sure it doesn't get sent to a SPAM folder. I only need to send, not read emails.

Much of the tutorials I see out there are for sending emails using Gmail. I would like to send myself an email from another one of my emails (using IMAP).

For example

```
from me1@example.com to me2@example.com -subject='Completed Task' -body='Task Complete, please review.'
```

As I would like to make sure this gets sent properly, I'd like to setup the package(s) so that it has all of the credentials as you would via a GUI app such as Thunderbird.

I am using Ubuntu server 18

Thanks for your help of pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: IMAP is **not** for sending e-mail, it is to read e-mail which is stored on a remote server.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why the question got voted down but I appreciate the feedback. Since the clarification made, having a question on the subject of sending an email via CLI, from a personal domain, can't be out of the realm of questions to be asked on a forum. I fit's a matter of it being presented in the wrong area, please relay that so that I may direct it there. Again, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using ssmtp. Mail is sent via SMTP protocol.

With ssmtp you can send mail via simple one line commands like:

```
echo "testmail" | ssmtp your@email.com
```

[ssmtp(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ssmtp.8.html)